# Optimize ratio of two positive convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am trying to minimize this function over x. If it is convex -- there should be no problem. But I doubt that it is convex. Any algorithmic thoughts?

$$F(\mathbf{x})= \frac{|\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{x}|}{\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{x}}$$

where $\mathbf{a},\, \mathbf{x}$ are real-valued vectors and $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is a positive-definite matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $F(x) \geq 0$. Since $\Sigma$ is positive definite, the system
$$
\Sigma x = b
$$

has a solution for any $b$. It then suffices to pick any $0 \neq b \in \mathrm{span}(a)^{\perp}$ and $x = \Sigma^{-1} b$, since
$$
F(\Sigma^{-1} b) = \frac{\langle \Sigma a, \Sigma^{-1} b \rangle}{\|b\|^2_{\Sigma^{-1/2}}} =
\frac{\langle a, b \rangle}{\|b\|_{\Sigma^{-1/2}}^2} = 0,
$$
since $b \in \mathrm{span}(a)^{\perp} \implies \langle a, b \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Hi I like your answer, but I forgot to mention that there are constraints on x. x will be orthogonal to a but the elements of x will be constrained to be positive and their sum will be constrained to be 1. Will this change anything in the approach?

Comment: I don't have any immediate thoughts, but this is important information that should be added to your original post.

Comment: Just curious, how about maximizing the inverse?
Or maximizing the quadratic term subject to constraint on the absolute value term and any other constraints.

Comment: It's not clear to me that this would help. The denominator is convex, so maximizing it is likely difficult.